# why is cordova downloading gradle again?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to run my ionic 2 app on my android phone. I have installed the android sdk and gradle. But when i run `cordova run android`, it starts downloading the 3.3 version of gradle while my gradle version is 3.5. Also, the download got stuck somewhere for 20 minutes so i stopped it .
Why is this happening?

gradle -v` returns

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-04-10 13:37:25 UTC
Revision:     b762622a185d59ce0cfc9cbc6ab5dd22469e18a6

Groovy:       2.4.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_121 (Oracle Corporation 25.121-b13)
OS:           Linux 3.16.0-77-generic amd64
```

`cordova run android` =>

```
`ANDROID_HOME=/home/user6/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
[12:37:44]  lint finished in 76.80 s 
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
.
<followed by a series of dots>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you installed gradle is in different location than the one which the cordova is looking for when u run using `cordova run android`.

As far as I know you need not install gradle explicitly when you use cordova.

Reference here - [Android Builds Now Using Gradle By Default](https://phonegap.com/blog/2015/09/28/android-using-gradle/).

Check the Android SDK path libraries and JAVA_HOME path. As of now I am not sure where the general path will be. It should be installed along with Android SDK.

Else, uninstall your preinstalled gradle. Let cordova download the gradle parts once. Next time it should not download when u run it.

Check this [Configuring Gradle](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#configuring-gradle) documentation. It might help you.